# Bash interactive - entire script writing to history

Tags: bash

Occasionally I throw together an interactive mode script using the shebang as such:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash -i
```

For some reason of recent, any scripts run in this mode have written their entire contents to my `.bash_history` file.

**For example:**

> Contents of **test.sh:**
>
> ```
> #!/usr/bin/env bash -i
>
> echo "hello"
> ```

```
13:54:50 ツ :~ >./test.sh 
hello

13:54:53 ツ :~ >history | tail -4

89969  #!/usr/bin/env bash -i
89970  echo "hello"
89971  ./test.sh 
89972  history | tail -4
```

If I **don't** have this line in my `.bash_profile`:

```
shopt -s histappend
```

Then the problem doesn't occur - but I lose my entire history each time I open a new Terminal tab.

All options in `.bash_profile` that relate to history are as follows:

```
shopt -s histappend
set +H
export HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
export HISTSIZE=100000
export HISTFILESIZE=100000
export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: Why do you run non-interactive scripts with an interactive shell?

Comment: `-i` is for interactive shells.  why run the script in an interactive shell when it's not?

Comment: Mainly for testing and to alter trapping behaviour.  Regardless, I used to be able to do this without the whole contents of the script being written to the history.

Comment: IMHO, this is the correct behaviour. Typing the lines of the script into an interactive shell should save every line in the history.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've thought about that.  Perhaps if I was trying this for the first time and it did this, I would assume that to be the case, but I know for a fact it hasn't always been the case - also - why would `histappend` being off stop this from happening ?  that option has nothing to do with the immediate history in the session, rather the history of that session as a whole.

Comment: I'm using GNU Bash v4.4.23 on Mac OS X. I don't seem to be able to reproduce this behavior. Could you update your question to include your Bash and OS version information?